# How to change content if the page is requested from a specific url in django?

Tags: python, django, backend, web-deployment

Say I have two pages one is example.com/login and another page is example.com/admin
And when I put the credentials on the login page I get redirected to the admin page.
Admin page has a logout button. If I press that button then it redirects me to the login page again.
**What I exactly want to do is, I want to display a message "Login again" dynamically (I know how to display a message dynamically) but only when user gets redirected from the login page via admin panel.**
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that either by:

1. Using Session:
   upon logout you set a variable in the session, that this user has been loged out.

```
    logout(request)
    request.session['logged_out'] = True
```

2. Get parameter:
   add a parameter to the redirected login url, if you find that parameter show you message, if there is no parameter you don't have to show.

```
    redirect('login/?logged-out=True')
```

in both cases you have to check in your view, and add a a property to check with in your context.

Comment: I didn't understand the first method, but the second method worked for me. Thank you. ❤️